# Android App Crash when using Stetto with Dialog Fragment Dismiss

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object com.facebook.stetho.inspector.elements.ElementInfo.parentElement' on a null object reference
```

I used the stetto (http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) for the network and database inspector for my android app.My app takes the following steps. Open Activity and Fragment -> Open DialogFragment + send request -> Open nested DialogFragment(into childFragmentManager) -> Close nested DialogFragment -> Close DialogFragment(back to Activity) and i get an error message.
I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work, but I don't know why one of the children of ElementInfo is null. And I see the same problem in the past, sorry if there is a solution, but I cannot find it.

Comment: There's an open issue regarding this on their repo: https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/652

Comment: You could migrate to [Facebook's Flipper](https://github.com/facebook/flipper) which already covers most features of Stetho and is actively maintained.

Comment: can we inspect database also?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect database too.